# How to prevent the resolved field in yarn.lock from being secretly modified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend, yarnpkg

I am a team leader. Recently I found a security vulnerability in the yarn model. For example, there is a section in yarn.lock:

```
react-native-ios-settings-bundle@1.2.2: 
version "1.2.2" 
resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-native-ios-settings-bundle/-/react-native-ios-settings-bundle-1.2.2.tgz#01ad1d116ec0ed1d975e1d1419669085c86c5171" 
integrity sha512-ttvVoR0GL4I2vfQ48JP+Gv3mLHtxVKQpFCUZOPeTZWMZRQA6YdilipsVCJ/7VEck71/ZwHUtGK/Q/wx/oH6Hpg==
```

If a member modifies the `resolved` and `integrity` fields when submitting a PR, such as:

```
react-native-ios-settings-bundle@1.2.2: 
version "1.2.2"
resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/hack-react-native-ios-settings-bundle/-/hack-react-native-ios-settings-bundle-1.2.2.tgz#01ad1d116ec0ed1d975e1d1419669085c86c5171"
integrity sha512-4nHAYwnemFJLzVJPl5dhNB+WQgNp41MLJjyYCypatMZl2GJD+EVXnu5eSUQE+UOpaIEhSVtqK5Y3OQ93hMhosQ==
```

I changed the resolved url and integrity to a hacker version. Usually there will be large-scale modifications in yarn.lock, and this modification will not be noticed by reviewers. Then users may install the hacked version of the npm package. Is this a security risk or have I missed something?

If it is a security risk, I have thought of two solutions:

1. Add a script lint to check yarn.lock for each PR
2. Do not allow developers to modify yarn.lock in the commit, and all modifications are automatically submitted by GitHub actions